Bound for difference between harmonic function and minimal surface
Given a bounded domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and a function $g:\partial D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, consider the two functions $u,v:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $u$ is harmonic ($u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$) and $v$ is a minimal surface ($\nabla\cdot(\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla v}|^2})=0$) both satisfying the Dirichlet boundary condition $u=v=g$ on $\partial D$.
It is known that $v$ is close to $u$ whenever the $|\nabla v|<<1$, but is there a concrete bound for their difference? maybe something like
$$\max_D|u-v|\leq F(|\nabla v|)$$
Edit: F can also depend on $g$ and $D$

Do you allow $F$ to depend on $g$? If so then I think it follows from relatively simple estimates from elliptic regularity theory

@JackT Yes, see edit

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and suppose that $u,v\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline \Omega)$ satisfy $\Delta u =0$ in $\Omega $, $\operatorname{div} \big ( \frac{\nabla v}{\sqrt{1+\vert \nabla v\vert^2}} \big )=0 $ in $\Omega$, and $u=v=g$ on $\partial \Omega$. Expanding out the divergence in the minimal surface equation, we find that $$ 0= \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(\nabla v) \partial_{ij}v \tag{$\ast$}$$ where $$a^{ij}(p)=\delta_{ij}- \frac{p_ip_j}{1+\vert p \vert^2} \qquad p \in \mathbb R^n$$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Observe that, for all $\zeta\in \mathbb R^n$, $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(p)\zeta_i\zeta_j = \vert \zeta \vert^2 - \frac{(p\cdot \zeta)^2}{1+\vert p \vert^2}\geq \frac{\vert \zeta\vert^2}{1+\vert p \vert^2} $$ by the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, $(\ast)$ is uniformly elliptic with ellipticity constant $$\lambda = \frac 1  {1+\| \nabla v \|^2_{L^\infty(\Omega)}}. $$
Now consider $w:=u-v$. In $\Omega$, we have that \begin{align*}
\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}(\nabla v) \partial_{ij}w &= \sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}(\nabla v) \partial_{ij}u\\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^n \tilde a_{ij}(\nabla v) \partial_{ij}u
\end{align*} where $$\tilde a_{ij}(p)=-\frac{p_ip_j}{1+\vert p \vert^2} \qquad p \in \mathbb R^n . $$ Call $$f =\sum_{i,j=1}^n \tilde a_{ij}(\nabla v) \partial_{ij}u  $$ so $$\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}(\nabla v) \partial_{ij}w = f \qquad \text{in }\Omega .$$ Moreover, $w=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Next, the maximum principle for equations with a right hand side (see Theorem 3.7 in the book of Gilbarg and Trudinger for example), it follows that \begin{align*}
\| u-v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}&\leq C \sup_\Omega \bigg ( \frac f \lambda \bigg ) \\
&= C (1+\| \nabla v\|^2_{L^\infty(\Omega)}) \| f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}
\end{align*} with $C$ depending only on the diameter of $\Omega$ denoted $\operatorname{diam}\Omega$. Since $$\| f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq \sum_{i,j=1}^n \| \tilde a _{ij}(\nabla v) \|\|\partial_{ij}u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} $$ and $$\| \tilde a _{ij}(\nabla v) \| \leq \frac{\| \nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2}{1+\| \nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2}, $$ so $$\| f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq \frac{C\| \nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2 \| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}}{1+\| \nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2}  $$ with $C$ depending only on $n$. Finally, elliptic regularity theory gives that $$\| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C \| g\|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)} $$ with $C$ depending only on $n$ and the $C^{2,\alpha}$ regularity of the boundary of $\Omega$.
All in all, we obtain $$\| u-v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C \| \nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2 \| g\|_{L^\infty(\partial \Omega)} $$ with $C$ some constant depending on $n$ and $\Omega$, so you can take $F(t) = C\| g\|_{L^\infty(\partial \Omega)} t^2$.
My opinion, however, is for these estimates to be more meaningful, you can't allow $F$ to depend on $g$ since elliptic regularity theory implies that I can control all derivative of $u$ and $v$ (provided $\| \nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$ is small) in terms of $g$, so I can always get rid of any $u$ and $v$ dependence with something in terms of $g$.

It is going to take me some time to make sure I understand everything. Is this your own proof or one can find this result in some textbook?

For sure. Yes, it's my own proof
